# ¿Cómo se puede obtener la MAC de una pc cliente en PHP?

Tags: php, redes

Estoy haciendo una aplicación php y necesito validar las pc que tengan acceso a la misma pero no se cómo se puede obtener desde el servidor la dirección mac que es única para cada pc cliente.

Obtengo el IP de esta forma, pero este está sujeto a cambios por el DHCP configurado en la red.

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Comment: Buenas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php Tal vez te sirva, creo que responde lo que estas preguntando. Saludos.

Comment: Hermano estuve revisando el enlace que me sugeriste pero en todos los ejemplos que probé la dirección MAC que logro obtener es la del servidor, no la del cliente. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

> MAC opera en la capa 2 del modelo OSI, encargada de hacer fluir la información libre de errores entre dos dispositivos conectadas directamente. Para ello se generan tramas, pequeños bloques de información que contienen en su cabecera las direcciones MAC correspondiente al emisor y receptor de la información. [Desde wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direcci%C3%B3n_MAC)

Esto quiere decir que no se puede obtener la dirección MAC desde fuera de la red local, ya que la dirección MAC solo sirve para controlar el enlace físico. Cuando una red local necesita conectarse con otra, se genera una interfaz por medio del router que generalmente usa un mecanismo llamado [NAT](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traducci%C3%B3n_de_direcciones_de_red), entonces se pierde el acceso a las direcciones MAC de la otra red (a menos que exista una máquina en la red local que pueda escanear las direcciones y enviarlas afuera). Adicionalmente el router y los dispositivos conectados a la red mantienen el mapa de direcciones IP-MAC en una [tabla de enrutamiento (ARP)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_resoluci%C3%B3n_de_direcciones) para localizar a los demas dispositivos.

Quizá se pueda abordar tu problema con un firewall configurable por Apis o tengas que implementar un mecanismo de autorización por contraseña o tokens como en [OAuth](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Answer (score 0):

por lo que tengo entendido PHP no tiene ninguna función nativa para obtener la dirección MAC, si hacer un print_r de $_SERVER verás que no la recibes...

Lo único que veo que puede funcionar es ejecutar un comando de unix/windows desde tu servidor.

Aquí tienes más info:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929212/getting-network-client-mac-address-syntax-issue-using-php

Espero que te ayude!

Un saludo!

Comment: Eso sólo funciona si el dispositivo está conectado directamente ( cable a cable ) con el servidor

Answer (score 0):

No se puede, la dirección MAC viaja sólo al siguiente dispositivo, el switch, módem o donde está conectada la tarjeta. Ahí se reemplaza por la del dispositivo y el siguiente pone la suya y así.
En explorer localmente la puedes obtener con Javascript y tal vez envíarla, pero el nivel de seguridad de eso es similar a la de poner una cookie con un ID único, yo usaría lo segundo que funciona con todos los browsers

Comment: En el caso de la cookie, qué ID sería único para reconocer a una pc?

Comment: tu creas el id y lo grabas, podrías usar la que te da la session de php

Answer (score 0):

Digo yo que si es cierto que se puede llamar con javascript, también se podrá almacenar su valor en una cookie y problema resuelto. Yo he llegado hastas aquí buscando lo mismo, pero lo mío es por otra razón. Estoy programando un foro, donde quiero que se pueda publicar sin estar reg y luego se pueda editar por el usuario que lo ha creado el tema. Las opciones son ip, poco fiable porque puede cambiar, una cookie con un valor para identificar al usuario o la MAC. No se me ocurren más. creo que me quedaré con el segundo métido

Comment: Más que una respuesta, es un comentario, la zona de respuestas es exclusivo solo para respuestas, quizás este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) te ayude

Answer (score 0):

La IP no es poco fiable sólo por el hecho que que pueda cambiar, sino además, porque puede estar compartida con otros dispositivos, lo cual hace imposible identificar a uno en concreto.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).